# Путь к картинке для джаваскрипта в Таймлиф

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Код джаваскрипта:

```
function fromPinkToBlue(){
document.querySelector('#img').src = '../static/images/x2coin.png'
document.querySelector('#img').setAttribute('style', 'width: 300px; height: 300px')
```

}

Как вы видите,  я меняю расположение  УЖЕ существующей картинки, но дело в том, что расположение к первому изображению прописано в тайм лиф (снизу хтмл код), а чтобы заменить картинку, путем изменения расположения к этой же картинке, нужно каким то образом прописать в хтмл и это расположение. Скрипт изменяет изображение, но сервер его не видит
HTML:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/conflip.css" th:href="@{/css/conflip.css}">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
          xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JADEN</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../static/circle-16.ico" th:href="@{/circle-16.ico}"  type="image/x-icon">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <title>Jaden</title>

</head>



    <body>


<a href="javascript:show_hide('block')"><img id="img"  src="../static/images/x1coin.png" th:src="@{/images/x1coin.png}" class="image"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></img></a>

        <br>
        <br><input type="submit" id="flipX" value="Flip!">

    </body>


<script type="module" src="../static/js/flipper.js" th:src="@{/js/flipper.js}"></script>
</html> ```
````

Comment: Наверное потому, что путь на сервере до картинок `../static/images/x1coin.png` а вы задаете `x2coin.png`

Comment: @SwaD наверное я вставил старый код(исправил). Все же, не работает, таймлиф скорее всего от джаваскрипта просит таймлифовский путь к картинке
Консоль браузера: GEThttp://localhost:8080/static/images/x2coin.png Путь полностью верный

Comment: Т.е. вы меняете значение и картинки нет? Картинка есть в каталоге static/images/x2coin.png? Код загрузки в консоли 404?

Comment: @SwaD Да, меняю путь расположение фотографии, чтобы появлялась другая, за место первой. Картинка есть в каталоге, в секьюрити конфиге указана папка images. Да, ошибка 404

Comment: А вы уверены, что каталог static/images/ правильный смотрите? Возможно ваш локальный сервер смотрит на другой каталог? Тут вопрос, откуда локальный сервер тянет картинки. Как эксперимент, удалите картинку из того каталога static/images/ из которого вы думаете берутся картинки и посмотрите на результат. Просто магии не бывает и что то явно напутано. Если в правильном каталоге есть картинка, то 404 быть не может

Comment: @SwaD спасибо за попытку помочь мне, я решил проблему. Стоило в джсе путь прописать images/x1coin.png , странно конечно, ну да ладно

Comment: Ну как говорится, чем смог...

Answer (score 0):

В коде джаваскрипта путь в моем случае, нужно было прописать вот так:
images/x2coin.png